# Passing an array into a block

Tags: arrays, ruby, comparison

I am a little lost on the block below.

```
def sort_string(string)
  string.split(" ").sort{|a,b| a.length <=> b.length}.join(" ")
end
```

The array is sorted based on the length (least to greatest). My confusion comes from what the variable `b` in the block of code is.

If I split the string `"example string here"` into an array and then sort it, how is `[example],[string],[here]` passed into the block `{|a,b| a.length <=> b.length}`? I don't understand how the elements of the array are passed into the code and then compared.

Comment: Where did you think `[[example],[string],[here]]` come from? That kind of thing is never passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `sort`, Ruby passes two objects into the block. They are to be compared, either using the built-in [`<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) method, or by some machination you devise that determines whether one is less-than (`-1`), equal-to (`0`), or greater-than (`1`) the other. So, `a` is one and `b` is the other.

Meditate on this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle # => [4, 1, 3, 2]
  .sort { |i, j|
    [i, j] # => [4, 1], [4, 3], [1, 3], [4, 2], [3, 2], [1, 2]
    i <=> j # => 1,      1,      -1,     1,      1,      -1
  }
  # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Remember what `<=>` does and compare the values returned for the `i <=> j` comparison each time through the loop.

But of course you knew this from reading the documentation for `sort`:

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-sort

Comment: The enumerable doc helped. I was going off of the array doc and was a bit lost.

Comment: I mean to spend time thinking about it. It's a common phrase in the Perlmonks world.

Comment: It should have been "Meditate". Auto spell-check jumped in.

Comment: I vote that this should be the new explanation in the docs. This is as great of an answer as I could have hoped for. Thank you.